# Bulk delete users from Google Cloud Identity Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-identity

I've been googling around, reading the google cloud platform docs but can't find the answer to bulk deleting users from the Identity Platform.

We have a dev application that we use for testing. We want to remove all authenticated users and start fresh. See below the image where I multi select and get no option to delete all the users.

[image: Identity Platform Multi user management]

I've searched for gcloud cli commands to do this but with no luck, the documentation on this functionality is not well surfaced.

I would be happy with answers to:

- Bulk delete through the G cloud UI
- Delete ALL authenticated users through gcloud cli
- Delete all users per tenant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the [Identity Toolkit API](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest) for **bulk deleting users**.

If you read through the [Admin APIs guide for Identity Platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/concepts-admin-auth-api) on Google Cloud, you will also notice that they recommend using the Admin APIs for user management.

---

What you are looking for is:

- [`projects.accounts.lookup`](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.accounts/lookup) for looking up all users (or [`projects.tenants.accounts.lookup`](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.tenants.accounts/lookup) if you want to look up for a *specific tenant*).
- [`projects.accounts.bachDelete`](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.accounts/batchDelete) for bulk-deleting users in your project (or [`projects.tenants.accounts.batchDelete`](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.tenants.accounts/batchDelete) if you want to target a *specific tenant*).

Comment: Awesome! Not exactly what I'm hoping for but we did build a CLI that does our migrations and handles that for us. We will add it in there. If it solves our problem then I'll come mark as correct. Thanks again, will know by tomorrow morning.